# Spring Redis: Range query "greater than" on a field

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis to store some data and later query it and update it with latest information.

Considering an example:

I receive File data, which carries info on the file and the physical storage location of that file.

- One shelf has multiple racks, and each rack can have multiple files.
- Each file has a version field, and it gets updated (incremented) when an operation on file is performed.

How do I plan to store?

- I need to query based on "shelfID + rack ID" -- To get all files.
- I need to query based on "shelfID + rack ID + version > XX" -- To get all files with version more than specified.

Now, to get all files belonging to a shelf and rack, is achievable in Spring Data Redis.
I create a key of the combination of 2 ID's and later query based on this Key.

```
  private <T> void save(String id, T entity) {
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(id, entity);
  }
```

But, how do I query for version field?
I had kept "version" field as @Indexed, but spring repository query does not work.

```
@RedisHash("shelves")
public class ShelfEntity {

  @Indexed
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Indexed
  private String shelfId;

  @Indexed
  private String rackId;

  @Indexed
  private String fileId;

  @Indexed
  private Integer version;

  private String fileName;    

  // and other updatable fields
}
```

Repository method:

```
List<ShefEntity> findAllByShelfIdAndRackIdAndVersionGreaterThan(String centerCd,
      String floorCd, int version);
```

Above, gives error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GREATER_THAN (1): [IsGreaterThan,
> GreaterThan]is not supported for redis query derivation

- Q. How do I query based on Version Greater than?
- Q. Is it even possible with Spring Data Redis?
- Q. If possible, how should I model the data (into what data structure), in order to make such queries?
- Q. If we don't use Spring, how to do this in Redis using redis-cli and data structure?

---

May be something like:

<key, key, value>
<shelfId+rackId, version, fileData>

I am not sure how to model this in Redis?

---

Update 2:
One shelf can have N racks.
One rack can have N files.
Each file object will have a version.
This version gets updated (o -> 1 -> 2....)

I want to store only the latest version of a file.
So, if we have 1 file object
shelfId - 1
rackId - 1
fileId - 1
version - 0
.... on update of version ... we should still have 1 file object.
version - 1

I tried keeping key as a MD5 hash of shelfId + rackId, in hash data structure.
But cannot query on version.

I also tried using a ZSet.

Saving it like this:

```
  private void saveSet(List<ShelfEntity> shelfInfo) {
    for (ShelfEntity item : shelfInfo) {
      redisTemplate.opsForZSet()
          .add(item.getId(), item, item.getVersion());
    }
  }
```

So, version becomes the score.

But the problem is we cannot update items of set.
So for one fileId, there are multiple version.
When I query, I get duplicates.

Get code:

```
Set<ShelfEntity> objects = (Set<ShelfEntity>) (Object) redisTemplate.opsForZSet()
        .rangeByScore(generateMd5Hash("-", shelfId, rackId), startVersion,
            Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

> Now, this is an attempt to mimic version > XX

Comment: No, that's not possible using Redis Repository directly. Why don't you store in RDMS to do complex query?

Comment: Can you list down all your access patterns?

Comment: @sonus21 Thanks for your comment. May I know what access pattern? I may need to query on aforesaid: findAllByShelfIdAndRackIdAndVersionGreaterThan

Comment: What other queries do you want to perform on this ShelfEntity collection/items/tables?

Comment: Prime search is for version. As said: find by the shelfId, rackId and version > XX.
Apart from this, it will be find by shelfId + rackId + fileId (to get that exact file)

Comment: How many records you would expect? Can't you apply these filters locally? You use a list to append them and read all of them and filter out what you don't need. Also what's unique in this collection, IIUC `id` and `shelfId,rackId` would be unique

Comment: 3M to 4M records initially, and then increasing over time. So handling in mem after fetching all does not make sense. "id" field is just an MD5 hash of combination. A unique key combination would be "shelfId + rackId + fileId" (one shelf, and one rack can have multiple files)

Comment: I don't see fileId in the entity, maybe you can update the entity.

Comment: Done. But the most important way to search, for my requirement, is for "shelfId + rackId and version > XX"

Comment: @sonus21 See my latest update..

Comment: The answer is added to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Create ZSET for each `shelfId` and `rackId` combination

Use two methods to save and update records in Redis

```
// this methods stores all shelf info in db
public void save(List<ShelfEntity> shelfInfo) {
    for (ShelfEntity item : shelfInfo) {
      redisTemplate.opsForZSet()
          .add(item.getId(), clonedItem, item.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Use update to remove old and insert new one, Redis does not support key update as it's a table so you need to remove the existing and add a new record

```
public void update(List<ShelfEntity> oldRecords, List<ShelfEntity> newRecords) {
    if (oldRecords.size() != newRecords.size()){
       throw new IlleagalArgumentException("old and new records must have same number of entries");
    }
    for (int i=0;i<oldRecords.size();i++) {
      ShelfEntity oldItem = oldRecords.get(i);
      ShelfEntity newItem = newRecords.get(i);
      redisTemplate.opsForZSet().remove(oldItem.getId(), oldItem); 
      redisTemplate.opsForZSet()
          .add(newItem.getId(), newItem, newItem.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Read items from ZSET with score.

```
List<ShefEntity> findAllByShelfIdAndRackIdAndVersionGreaterThan(String shelfId,
      String rackId, int version){
    Set<TypedTuple<ShelfEntity>> objects = (Set<TypedTuple<ShelfEntity>>)  redisTemplate.opsForZSet()
        .rangeWithScores(generateMd5Hash("-", shelfId, rackId), new Double(version),
            Double.MAX_VALUE);


    List<ShelfEntity> shelfEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TypedTuple<ShelfEntity> entry:  objects) {
      shelfEntities.add(entry.getValue().setVersion( entry.getScore().intValue()));
    }
    return shelfEntities;
  }
```

Comment: Ah! I used ZSet to make some progress but the part of setting version as null as its available as score, was missing from my mind.
Its my 2nd day with Redis, but quite a learning.
I'll update my code with this and try!

Comment: But, if a data in entity gets updated, I will get duplicate records in ZSet for same shelfId, rackId & fileId.
I forgot to add more field in entity, but as I mentioned that a version gets updated when an operation is performed (Lets say some one changed file name).

Now I have 2 records for same file with 2 file name.

Comment: This is causing the Get query to return duplicate records. (I do not want to filter in App code)

Comment: Not sure about the other contents of this file, you should assign fix `fileId` to each file, on each update only version should change in Redis, not the `fileId`. Actual `fileId` could be `fileId#version`, you need to change how you handle the file change event.

Comment: Its not about any ID. Any data(field) update on the entire object, creates a new record in ZSet. Not just fileId#version. An update in name of file, will NOT update fileId. But the version (score) will change. And I need to store the new updated name as well. Isn't it what an update should do?

Comment: ZSets (or Set) do not allow update in the existing object.

Comment: "Reset version to avoid duplicate records" -> Duplicate records gets created with any field (not to search but important) even with this!

Comment: If you know something is being changed, then it can be replaced, it would be a two-step commands.

Comment: Do you mean read and update?
Are there no in place updates for any structure in Redis?
Sorry.. saw your answer update now!